# Google Sheets - Array Formula, match, lookup

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, match, lookup, array-formulas

I Just cant mange this - Help

Im trying to do something but just cant manage it.

If you look at the image below you will see Username, Sponsor, Referral 1, Referral 2.

IMAGE of spreadsheet - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRP1B.jpg

Now what i want to do with a formula is E&F or how ever i can do it to search Sponsor for using the corresponding usersname and if there is none i want to place No referrals in the referral 1 & referral 2. There will only ever be 2 referrals. Ive spent hours doing it but cant get it right.

I've tried Arrayformula, lookup and loads of other ways but new to spreadsheets and cant master this

Comment: Is my understanding correct in that, you want F&G to be blank if E is blank?

Comment: Either blank or say "No Referrals"   here is an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DMXDlBER1jQmPhBLPrxgzxx8-I7eB5KAid0ijkcXejA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In F6:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(D6:D),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D6:D,{E6:E,D6:D},2,0),"No Referrals"),))`

and in G6:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(D6:D),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D6:D,FILTER({E6:E,D6:D},(MATCH(E6:E,E6:E,0)+ROW(E6)-1)<ROW(E6:E)),2,0),"No Referrals"),))`

Comment: Adam, i tried it but no joy. i shared a copy of the spreadsheet if you could have a look - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DMXDlBER1jQmPhBLPrxgzxx8-I7eB5KAid0ijkcXejA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I pasted the exact formulae in to H6 and I6. Let me know how they are not working, and we can take it from there.

Comment: WOW and it fills in the whole column.... i had just got it working with this =if(A6:A="",,iferror(transpose(filter(D$6:D,E$6:E=D6))))

Comment: Oh sorry, bit of misunderstanding on my part - I saw "ArrayFormula" in your OP and thought you might want an "auto-filling" solution. If not, then the formula you posted in the comment above would be a great solution.

Comment: Adam i changes that spreadsheet and it now has a few more columns. How would i do the same as you have in F6 & G6 in H6,I6,K6 & L6. I want the code to fill in the whole column down to the last entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E6), "No Referrals")
```

in Col F&G, but AppScript is probably best for something like this.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][4].isblank()) {
        values[i][5].setvalue("No Referral");
        values[i][6].setvalue("No Referral");
    }
```

Loop through your data, check if E is blank, if it is, set F&G as "No Referral".